# ¿por que no me acomoda bien el icono?

Tags: html, bootstrap

buen día compañeros, tengo un problema, la verdad es que a la parte de diseño no le se mucho, ahorita lo que quiero es acomodar un icono al lado de un texto. pero no me deja. y en lugar de ponerlo a un lado lo pone arriba del texto. sale así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero quiero que salga.

el icono de la casa y a un lado el texto home.

el código lo tengo asi.

```
 <li class="nav-item">
                    <span class="fi fi-rr-home">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </span>
                </li>
```

todo eso lo tengo dentro de otra clase.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
```

ustedes que tienen más experiencia ¿me pueden ayudar, por favor :) ??

**mi codigo completo es este**

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar"
                aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Sistema PDF</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="offcanvas-body">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                        <div>
                            <span class="fi fi-rr-home"></span>
                        </div>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex mt-3" role="search">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: podes poner el html completo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu 'Home' ocupa toda la linea ya que es un elemento en bloque por defecto, agregale la clase d-inline y se arregla

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <span>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
        <a class="nav-link active d-inline" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Después tu elemento que contiene el icono está envolviendo el elemento del enlace a home, es preferible que estén separados, tal y como puse acá

Comment: ohhhh sii ya funciono :) muchas gracias

Comment: @lemuelAyanotfuentesAyala de nada!

Answer (score 0):

intenta creando un `<div>` que contenga el `<span>` y el `<a>` pero sin que el `<a>` este dentro del `<span>`,
tambien lo podes intentar sin crear el div

Comment: nop ... sigue igual :c